pwquality_pam.so is not behaving as the man page example says
The following is an example usage of pwquality_pam.so (Link to manpage).
#%PAM-1.0
#
# These lines allow a md5 systems to support passwords of at least 14
# bytes with extra credit of 2 for digits and 2 for others the new
# password must have at least three bytes that are not present in the
# old password
#
password  required pam_pwquality.so \
               difok=3 minlen=15 dcredit= 2 ocredit=2
password  required pam_unix.so use_authtok nullok md5

The problem is the comment states that passwords should contain at least 14 bytes. However I think this is wrong because of those extra credits. For example my PAM configuration accepts fu!!13371337 as  a valid password and doesn't accept 13371337133713 which contradicts the mentioned comment. My problem is with that comment rather than PAM accepting the password.
